# Determine WiFi end-point that my laptop is connected to

Tags: windows, powershell, wifi

I want to detect what wifi my laptop is connected against. I use following command

> netsh wlan show networks mode=BSSID

It lists all the available wireless end-points. How can I know which end-point my laptop is connected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a laptop to test with but I believe this PowerShell command should work.

Windows 8 and later:

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile | select Name
```

Windows 7:

```
netsh wlan show interfaces | select-string SSID
```

Comment: This doesn't give any info about what wifi  laptop is connected to. I had already tried this using wbemtest

Comment: Can you give an example of the info are you looking for?

Comment: Let's say in the available WiFi networks, there are two available options. WiFi1 and WiFi2. I connect my laptop to WiFi1. Through power-shell script, I want to retrieve WiFi1 as this is where my laptop is connected.

Comment: Give the updated answer a shot.

Comment: that's perfect, exactly what i was looking for